# Не выводится на печать google карта

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api, google-maps

На сайте, в разделе контакты, выводится карта. В js задаю lat,lng. Все работает нормально. Но вот при отправке страницы на печать карта пропадает со страницы, и остается только стилизованный маркер...

```js
$('#print').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.print();
});
```

```html
<a href="" id="print" class="btn-print">Распечатать</a>
```

В чем может быть проблема, и как ее решить?

```html
<div class="map">
  <a href="" id="print" class="btn-print js-pri print">Распечатать</a>
  <div class="google-maps" id="google-map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
    <div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;">
              <div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;">
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 777px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 777px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1033px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 521px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 521px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1033px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 265px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 265px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 9px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 9px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -247px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -247px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1289px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1289px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1545px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1545px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1801px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1801px; top: 194px;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div>
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div>
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1;">
              <div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;">
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 777px; top: -62px;">
                  <canvas draggable="false" height="256" width="256" style="-webkit-user-select: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 256px; width: 256px;"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 777px; top: 194px;">
                  <canvas draggable="false" height="256" width="256" style="-webkit-user-select: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 256px; width: 256px;"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1033px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 521px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 521px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1033px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 265px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 265px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 9px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 9px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -247px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -247px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1289px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1289px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1545px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1545px; top: 194px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1801px; top: -62px;"></div>
                <div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1801px; top: 194px;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;">
            <div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;">
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 777px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39612!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322117945!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 521px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39611!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322117945!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 777px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39612!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322117945!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1033px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39613!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322117945!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1033px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39613!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322117945!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 521px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39611!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322117945!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 265px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39610!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322097781!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 265px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39610!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322116505!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 9px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39609!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322076904!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 9px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39609!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322076904!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -247px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39608!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322076904!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -247px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39608!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322076904!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1289px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39614!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322053865!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1289px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39614!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322053865!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1545px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39615!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322104263!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1545px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39615!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322104263!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1801px; top: -62px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39616!3i20479!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322104263!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
              <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 1801px; top: 194px; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;">
                <img src="http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i16!2i39616!3i20480!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i322104263!3m9!2sru-RU!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div>
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div>
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div>
          <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <a target="_blank" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=55.776497,37.598771&amp;z=16&amp;t=m&amp;hl=ru-RU&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" title="Нажмите, чтобы отобразить эту область в Картах Google">
          <div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;">
            <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google4.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="padding: 15px 21px; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px; z-index: 10000002; display: none; width: 256px; height: 148px; position: absolute; left: 793px; top: 110px; background-color: white;">
        <div style="padding: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 16px;">Картографические данные</div>
        <div style="font-size: 13px;">Картографические данные © 2015 Google</div>
        <div style="width: 13px; height: 13px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;">
          <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt6.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gmnoprint" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; right: 281px; bottom: 0px; width: 209px;">
        <div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="-webkit-user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px;">
          <div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
            <div style="width: 1px;"></div>
            <div style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; display: none;">Картографические данные</a><span>Картографические данные © 2015 Google</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gmnoscreen" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); direction: ltr; text-align: right; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">Картографические данные © 2015 Google</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc" draggable="false" style="z-index: 1000001; -webkit-user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; position: absolute; right: 154px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
          <div style="width: 1px;"></div>
          <div style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/ru-RU_US/help/terms_maps.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Условия использования</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="-webkit-user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
          <div style="width: 1px;"></div>
          <div style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a target="_new" title="Сообщить об ошибке на карте или снимке" href="https://www.google.com/maps/@55.776497,37.5987706,16z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?source=apiv3&amp;rapsrc=apiv3" style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; position: relative;">Сообщить об ошибке на карте</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gmnoprint" draggable="false" controlwidth="28" controlheight="55" style="margin: 10px; -webkit-user-select: none; position: absolute; bottom: 69px; right: 28px;">
        <div class="gmnoprint" controlwidth="28" controlheight="55" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
          <div draggable="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer; width: 28px; height: 55px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            <div title="Увеличить" style="position: relative; width: 28px; height: 27px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
              <div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 15px; left: 7px; top: 6px;">
                <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 120px; height: 54px;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 67%; height: 1px; left: 16%; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);"></div>
            <div title="Уменьшить" style="position: relative; width: 28px; height: 27px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
              <div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 15px; left: 7px; top: 6px;">
                <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -15px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 120px; height: 54px;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

добавил html-код, который выводится во время печати

Comment: Во всех браузерах все одинаково. Выводиться блок с логотипом, выводятся контакты, то что не надо спрятано. Есть отдельные стили для печати. Контейнер под карту есть, ему заданы все нужные параметры, даже выводиться маркер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо! 
Пару часов дебага проблемы и нашел в чем ошибка. Если не вы начинали проект, ВСЕГДА проверяйте не вставлял ли кто до вас стили для печати!! 
Действительно проблема была в стилях для печати...

Answer (score 0):

Без html кода страницы трудно определить. Я думаю проблема в стилях для печати. Задайте всем нужным блокам ширину и высоту. [CSS печатной версии страницы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/160997/)

```
@media print {

}
```

Comment: в @media print все нормально...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема явно в стилях или разметке. также, попробуйте распечатать в другом браузере, это может уточнить задачу.